# How to add plugin to all vuex actions?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vuex

I can add my plugin to all Vue components like by using Vue.use(myPlugin) and then access it via this.$myPlugin.

I want to call my plugin from vuex.

How can i make same thing with Vuex store actions?

The plugin is this:

```
const SwaggerApi = {
  install(Vue, options) {
    Swagger({
      url: 'http://localhost:3000/explorer/swagger.json',
      requestInterceptor(req) {
        req.headers['Accept'] = 'application/json'
        req.headers['content-type'] = 'application/json'
        req.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = 'http://localhost:3000'
        req.headers['Authorization'] = localStorage.getItem('token')
        return req
      }
    })
      .then((client) => {
        // console.log(client)
        client.spec.basePath = '/api'
        Vue.prototype.$swagg = client.apis // <=== What should be here?

      }, (error) => {
        console.error('failed to load api spec: %o', error)
      })
  }
}
```

I tried to add `Vue.use(SwaggerApi)` in my store, and 'Vuex.use(SwaggerApi)' and `plugins:[SwaggerApi]' to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok,  i found it. Its `Vuex.Store.$swagg = client.apis` and then `Vuex.Store.$swagg.myModel` etc.